# How can I get iText 7 to repeat the headers of a "Table" on each page of the generated?

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation

Do you know any alternative to the itextsharp PdfPTable in **itext** 7? I need to repeat 8 lines every page.
With itextsharp I did it  by:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
table.HeaderRows = 8;
```

and i need to do the same in **itext 7**